# Text being displayed with a blue underlining, where is it coming from?

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying some white text on a back background but the text is displayed with a blue line underneath it (regardless of the browser). Where is this coming from?

```
body {
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
    font-family: Helvetica; 
    margin: 0;              /* Amount of negative space around the outside of the body */
    padding: 0;             /* Amount of negative space around the inside of the body */
}

#main_header {
    position: relative;
}


#logo {
    position:absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#main_title {
    position:absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:white;
    top: 50px;
    left: 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}

<body>
    <a href="http://theurl">
    <div id = "main_header" >
        <img id = "logo" src="logo.png"/>       
        <h2 id = "main_title">Title</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/BQeQm/ do you see the underline here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor tags (`<a>`) cannot contain block elements such as `div` or `h2` in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A). This may be causing the effect you are seeing. [Read on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct).

You can rewrite your `<a>` tag to surround inline elements (below) only or specify that your document type is HTML5. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320404/wrap-link-a-around-div) are other solutions.

```
<body>
    <div id = "main_header" >
        <a href="http://theurl"><img id = "logo" src="logo.png"/></a>      
        <h2 id = "main_title">Title</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Aminoacids did you declare your document type?

Comment: I'd like to have the url invoked if any part of the main_header div is clicked, but if I extend the closing anchor tag to be after the h2 element then the blue line comes back. Any suggestions on how to remove it for that situation?

Comment: @Aminoacids Are you declaring your the document type `<!doctype html>` before your `<html>` tag on your page?

Comment: Yes. The first few lines are: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>

Answer (score 0):

try to set:

```
a img { border: none; }

a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting this with with Safari, but the change didn't affect the line.

Comment: Then try to unset `text-decoration` attribute too.