# Unwanted underlining appearing under text

Tags: html

I'm displaying some text and a blue line is appearing underneath it

http://jsfiddle.net/mungbeans/CmVsJ/

Same as this question

[Text being displayed with a blue underlining, where is it coming from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255029/text-being-displayed-with-a-blue-underlining-where-is-it-coming-from)

The answer to that and to others say it is invalid for html4 but valid for html5. Why does this problem occur with the fiddle in that case? Whats the solution?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text being displayed with a blue underlining, where is it coming from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255029/text-being-displayed-with-a-blue-underlining-where-is-it-coming-from)

Comment: It’s still the same question as previously asked. Being “valid” is just a formal issue.

Comment: That link and also one it references make it sound like it should work with html5. Are you saying that is not the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your code

```
<ul>
  <a href="http://whatever">
    <li id = "header_list">
      <div id = "main_title">title</div>
      <img id = "logo" src="logo.png"/>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

The div id="main_title" is within the anchor tag, meaning it is a link.  By default, link styles have the blue underline.  You could add the css style to remove the blue underline:

```
#main_title {text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
```

Also, you should put the li tags directly after ul, since it needs to be a direct child:

```
<ul>
  <li id = "header_list">
    <a href="http://whatever">
      <div id = "main_title">title</div>
      <img id = "logo" src="logo.png"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's coming from your `<a>` - because **everything** is wrapped in it. To remove it simply apply:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CmVsJ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the style for your links (all the text is within your `<a>` tags):

```
a{text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is inside an `<a>` tag which will be rendered with an underline by default. Change the default behavior by setting `text-decoration: none` for links and it should work.
`

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags `a` have an `text-decoration` definition of `underline` by default.
You can fix this by simply adding the `text-decoration: none;` attribute to your CSS definition.

I should also point out that your markup isn't entirely correct.  Your anchor should be within the list-item `li`, and it's generally not a good idea to have block elements `div` inside of inline-block elements `a`.

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle to demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/CmVsJ/2/