# An alternative for div inside anchor tag other than span?

Tags: html, css

I have a banner button, 600px width and 200px height. Half of that would be a plain background with text in the middle and the other half would be an image:

HTML:

```
<li class="banner">
    <a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <div class="image"></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li a {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
}

li p {
    background: #268388;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

li .image {
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The div inside anchor messes things up. Replacing the div with a span makes unwanted margins with other elements/spans that I also added.

What do I do? Any other alternative for that div (other than adding the image directly in the HTML)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alternatively use a pseudo element like `:after` ... that **doesn't add an unnecessary empty tag** to the markup:

```
li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
}
li p, li a:after {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;   
}
li p {
    float: left;
    background: #268388;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
li a:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/600x400) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I combined the overlapping rules, to make it a bit more dry.

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WZg37/11/)**

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'm going with this way, But now there's another weird problem, floating li p makes the anchor tag unclickable, it's not a button anymore, Nothing happens when I hover or click and the cursor doesn't change. It does on the psudeo image class but not on the paragraph area, That still happens when I keep the image on a div, I've no idea why.

Comment: for me it works ... see this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WZg37/11/). Did you add the **`href`** attribute to the anchor tag? Another problem could be if you're using any javascript that would disable the mose over or on-click events or that the image element is somehow placed in front of (=over) the `p` ... but otherwise it should work as it is now.

Comment: and here I added also some `:hover` and `:active` fun: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WZg37/15/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to float the `<div>` element as well:

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
}

a > p {
    float: left;
    background: #268388;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0; /* new */
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}

a > div {
    float: right; /* new */
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x200) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/WZg37/)

### Alternative

**HTML**

```
<a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x200) no-repeat 300px 0;
    /* alternatively as suggested by Martin Turjak */
    background: #268388 url(http://placehold.it/600x400) no-repeat top right;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}

a > p {
    background: #268388;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/JL2fs/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. floating fixed the div.
is it considered bad practice though? I mean having the div inside the anchor in this case?

Comment: @MagdiGamal The `<div>` inside the `<a>` element is valid HTML and it will work across all major browsers. I've added an alternative to my answer, that will also work among all browsers and has even a shorter markup and less CSS styles.

Comment: @insertusernamehere +1 heh, the simplest solution is usually best - why not just adding the background image to the anchor right - the only issue I see would be that you can not use `background-size: cover` anymore for different sized images but you would have to cast them to `background-size: 300px 200px` or something like that.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Thanks. That's the only part I also wonder about: Is the background image always in the right dimensions or must it be scaled. I mean, for a banner it would be great, if anything would be visible - especially on such a small size.

Comment: alternatively you could align the background right and scale it to the height of the anchor: [http://jsfiddle.net/JL2fs/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/JL2fs/1/), and then you can also have narrower images there.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Yeah true that, that's pretty nice, too. Together we broke it down very nicely to the most simple markup. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put a `<div>` inside of an `<a>`. For older browsers `<a>` elements should only have inline elements, a `<div>` is a block element. See [Wrap link <a> around <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320404/wrap-link-a-around-div)
I would redo the HTML and pad the `<a>` to stretch out to cover the entire containing`<div>`.  Float the new `<div>` and it's contained elements.
Something like:

**HTML**

```
<li class="banner">
<div id="newDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <a></a> 
</div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.newDiv a {display:block;width:x;height:x;padding:x;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with: `<strong>` or `<em>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little difference between a span and a div, by default div is `display: block` and span is `display: inline`. I would try changing them to `span` and adding the following css

```
a span.image { display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0;` to your `<p>` element:

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WZg37/6/)</kbd>

Code

```
ul {
    list-style-type : none;
}

li a {
    display : inline-block;
      width : 600px;
}

li p {
   line-height : 200px;        
    background : #268388;
    text-align : center;        
        height : 200px;
        margin : 0px;      /* This one */ 
         float : left;        
         width : 300px;            

}

li .image {
    background : silver;
        height : 200px;
         float : left;        
         width : 300px;       
}
```