# How can I exclude this element from an inherited link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site at [whensayfeed.meteor.com](http://whensayfeed.meteor.com). Each of those "Posts" is a nested in a `<a></a>` element. The heart on the right side of each one is supposed to be a "like button" so it also needs to be clickable. However, since it's nested in an `<a>` it just goes to that address when clicked. I need a way to either exclude this element, or do this in some other way. I've tried to just nest the `.chant` element in the link, but it doesn't pick up that click. What do you believe I should do?

Comment: css z-index should fix that problem. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I tried z-index, but it didn't work for me. Maybe I didn't do it right. Would you mind trying to debug it in browser and post solution?

Comment: when I clicked on your link it was just a blue screen.

Comment: I just tried it. Your right, it just takes a few seconds.

Comment: perhaps either return false or preventDefault may give you the result you are looking for. I tried going to the page but it's just blue with no posts.

Comment: What browser are you guys using? Both of my webkit browsers are working as well as my phone

Comment: I use firefox. Also where is this extra a tag that you want to click? The heart is an image no a tag around it. Also why is the content being wrapped in a anchor tag?

Comment: There is no tag. It does nothing right now. Eventually it will be an onclick event

Comment: whenever I inspect element nothing comes up in the inspector :\

Comment: Are you on a Mac or Windows machine? It works on my phone safari, safari, chrome, my brothers chrome. IDK what's going on

Comment: I am using a mac, firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80413/discussion-between-isaac-riley-wasserman-and-floor).

Comment: the href says "whenisay:/.../.../", have you wrote any javascript for it?, in that case use event.target which will give you the img target as source from which you can identify the mouse click happened on the heart img

Comment: I don't see a reason for you to make those nested anchor tags. Actually I don't see any reason to nest a tags. if you have a link and it needs to span   like a button (wider and longer then text) just apply div > link > text. then make link display block with height and width of 100%

Answer (score 1):

[Nesting  tags is illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

Try making your like button a link that's outside of the post link. You can then use position: absolute to overlap your like button on top of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set the `z-index: 0;` of `.post-contain` instead of previous `z-index: -20;`.

Have a function receiving `anchor` click events like so:

```
function onAnchorClicked(e){
 if(e.target.nodeName==='IMG'){
  console.log('Image clicked');
  e.preventDefault();
 }else{
  console.log('Anchor clicked');
 }
}
```

Assign the click event to all `anchor` tags: `$('a').on('click',onAnchorClicked);`

This way, you can do what you want to do when `img` is clicked.

Having said that, although [HTML5 does allow *block-level* elements to be nested inside an *anchor* tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032) but [legacy browsers will have a hard time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320470).

A solution to that perhaps could be to have your posts wrapped around a `div` element instead of `anchor` which [behaves like an anchor tag](https://css-tricks.com/when-and-when-not-to-use-an-anchor-tag/) accompanied by a `data-link` attribute with values containing your links that you can populate from backend e.g.:
`<div class="anchor-link" data-link="LINK GOES HERE">...</div>` and then assign the `click` as described above (changing the selector obviously).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This sort of helps. When I click the heart, it runs my onclick event, but shortly after goes to my link.

Comment: @IsaacRiley-Wasserman have you deleted the `img` tag? I don't see it on the website anymore. Also, your `init();` function doesn't work because `body`'s `onload()` event doesn't guarantee that your content has also loaded.

Comment: Use events exposed by Meteor such as `Template.FullFeed.onCreated`, `Template.FullFeed.onDestroyed` or most important in your case, `Template.FullFeed.onRendered` event. Do the things you do inside `init();` in this `onRendered` method.