# <a> link is not working on the div

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="gallery-cell">
  <div class="highslide-gallery">
    <a id="thumb2" href="imgs/SteakHouse/1.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionId: 'steak-caption', slideshowGroup:2 } )">
      <div id="txt">
        <h4><b>STEAK HOUSE<br>RESTAURANT</b></h4>
        <br>
        <!--- Delete this after adding Address --->
        <p class="address">
          <!-- Address -->
        </p>
        <p class="city">Jeddah</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="hidden-container">
      <a href="imgs/SteakHouse/2.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionId: 'steak-caption', thumbnailId: 'thumb2', slideshowGroup:2 })"></a>
      <a href="imgs/SteakHouse/3.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionId: 'steak-caption', thumbnailId: 'thumb2', slideshowGroup:2 })"></a>
      <a href="imgs/SteakHouse/4.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionId: 'steak-caption', thumbnailId: 'thumb2', slideshowGroup:2 })"></a>
      <a href="imgs/SteakHouse/5.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionId: 'steak-caption', thumbnailId: 'thumb2', slideshowGroup:2 })"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="highslide-caption" id="steak-caption">
      Name:
      <br><b>Steak House Restaurant</b>
      <br> Location:
      <br><b>Jeddah</b>
      <br>
      <!--Total Built Area:<br><b>495 M<sup>2</sup>/Unit</b>  <br>-->
      <!--Lot Area:<br><b>352 M<sup>2</sup>/Lot</b>           <br>-->
      <!--Year:<br><b>2012</b>                                <br><br>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<a>` element is the parent of the class "txt" and when I try to make `<a>` the parent of the entire "gallery-cell" class it doesn't work!
I want the entire cell to be clickable, not just the text.

If you want, take a look at this website to test it out: http://urbanphenomena.net/

Comment: You need to add display:block for 'a' tag in css.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320404/wrap-link-a-around-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, adding a div inside anchor tag is a wrong method.

So you can add the anchor tag as the first child of the "gallery-cell" div

```
<div class="gallery-cell">
    <a id="thumb2" href="imgs/SteakHouse/1.jpg" class="highslide"></a>
    <div class="highslide-gallery">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then give position relative to the "gallery-cell" and position absolute to the  tag. You can use following style

```
.gallery-cell {
   position: relative;
}

a#thumb2 {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Through this you can make entire cell to be clickable

Answer (score 0):

Since  element is inline by default and div is block, you need to define  element as block either. (block element in inline element is not valid)

Answer (score -1):

Add This CSS

```
.highslide-gallery {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.highslide {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    outline: medium none;
    width: 100%;
}
```