# How to use div like link to redirect to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to make div which will act simulate to `Link` element, so when you click on it you navigate to another page.

Something like this

```
<Link to="/employees">
   ...  
</Link>
```

But it has to be div.

I could use `onClick` but when I use it, I should use whole path `https://pro.websire.com/employees`. I don't want to use it because we have different versions of website.

So path should be exactly like in `Link`  element

```
<div onClick={to('/employees')}>
  ...
</div>
```

Does anyone know is it possible to do ?

Comment: you mean you wanted to redirect to external link?

Comment: @VLDCNDN Yes, sorry didn't know how to call it properly. I need my link to be like this /# in div element. Just like in Link

Comment: Wrap it in [`<a>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320404/wrap-link-a-around-div) like a normal link.

Comment: @Lain it <a> will ovveride style of child elements then

Comment: Are you using `react-router`? Your `Link` is kind of similar with it @KarinaShulan

Comment: @NickVu Yes, it's react-router

Comment: For correct HTML semantics and web accessibility you should definitely still be using the `Link`, or anchor tag, for linking to other pages. You can still use a `div` element, but wrap it in the `Link` component. If you ***must*** use the `div` element alone then be sure to add the correct accessibility attributes and styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using react router, you can programmatically navigate using the `useNavigate` [hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate). Inside your component, you need to do the following.

```
const LinkComponent = () =>{
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    return(<div onClick={() => navigate("/home")}>Link </div>)
}
```